# How do you build an infinite repeating stream from a finite stream in Java 8?

Tags: java, java-stream

How can I turn a finite Stream of things `Stream<Thing>` into an infinite repeating stream of things?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Comment: Yes, But when All I have in front of me is several failed attempts, when I'm looking for something I'd expect to be in a standard library, it's hard to pick just one of the failed attempts considering none of them are close, and have more to do with mapping the previous stream.

Comment: At least write a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You'd have to read that `Stream` into a `Collection` as a `Stream` can only be consumer once. So, in essence, you first need a `Supplier<Stream<?>>` rather than just a `Stream`.

Comment: @AlexCuadrón If I had a Minimal, Complete, Verifiable example I'd have the damned solution. I don't think you can get more minimal then `Stream<Thing>` and if it were Complete, then I would have my solution already.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach show us what you've tried

Comment: SO's obsession about 'showing what you have tried' is only applicable when you have a clear error. If this is to become a resource for someone else to use, there's already more then enough information, I don't see how bloating it with fluff that doesn't give any further insight helps. If the question was something other then a basic streaming operation, I'd understand.

Comment: Also If you think it's low effort, I dare you to try to find a duplicate question, I've already been hunting.

Comment: without code this is just another `give-me-teh-codez` post

Comment: Sure it is, it's also something that is probably either in the standard library that I'm too blind to see, or not, and isn't trivial. Doesn't mean it won't be a good resource and answer a question that appears to be missing on SO.

I've tried reading docs, I've tried searching SO, and I've been unable to come up with pretty much anything that's elegant enough to share, even if wrong.

Comment: To whomever voted too broad, how else would you phrase the question?

What is unclear of the result?

Comment: For what purpose do you need the infinite stream of things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Boris the Spider is right:  a Stream can only be traversed once, so you need a `Supplier<Stream<Thing>>` or you need a Collection.

```
<T> Stream<T> repeat(Supplier<Stream<T>> stream) {
    return Stream.generate(stream).flatMap(s -> s);
}

<T> Stream<T> repeat(Collection<T> collection) {
    return Stream.generate(() -> collection.stream()).flatMap(s -> s);
}
```

Example invocations:

```
Supplier<Stream<Thing>> stream = () ->
    Stream.of(new Thing(1), new Thing(2), new Thing(3));

Stream<Thing> infinite = repeat(stream);
infinite.limit(50).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);

System.out.println();

Collection<Thing> things =
    Arrays.asList(new Thing(1), new Thing(2), new Thing(3));

Stream<Thing> infinite2 = repeat(things);
infinite2.limit(50).forEachOrdered(System.out::println);
```

Comment: Thanks, together with Boris you helped me get most of the way there, and whilst it solved the issue I was having, it didn't answer the question as written. If you provide an example that contains an intermediate collection made from a Stream, I'll delete my answer and accept yours.

Answer (score 2):

If you have Guava and a Collection handy, you can do the following.

```
final Collection<Thing> thingCollection = ???;
final Iterable<Thing> cycle = Iterables.cycle(thingCollection);
final Stream<Thing> things = Streams.stream(cycle);
```

But this doesn't help if you have a Stream rather then a Collection.

Comment: Why can't you just call `Streams.stream(cycle)`?

Comment: Nice pickup. I was originally following the guava docs, but that's quicker. I guess they were referring to my other answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have a finite Stream, and know that it fits in memory, you can use a intermediate collection.

```
final Stream<Thing> finiteStream = ???;
final List<Thing> finiteCollection = finiteStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
final Stream<Thing> infiniteThings = Stream.generate(finiteCollection::stream).flatMap(Functions.identity());
```

Comment: Alternatively, `Stream.generate(() -> finiteCollection).flatMap(List::stream)`.

Comment: Is there much difference?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.