# Behavior of Stream.generate method when passed a Supplier<Stream<T>> argument

Tags: java, lambda, parameters, java-8, java-stream

After reading [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48119039/1876620) and [one of its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48119590/1876620), I decided to run some tests on my own. To my surprise, I came to a situation that looks quite strange.

Here's the code:

```
public class InfiniteRepeatingStream {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Stream<Integer> s1 = repeatFromSupplier(() -> Stream.of(1, 2, 3));
        s1.sequential().limit(10).forEachOrdered(System.out::print);

        System.out.print("\n----------------\n");

        Stream<Integer> s2 = repeatFromStream(Stream.of(1, 2, 3));
        s2.sequential().limit(10).forEachOrdered(System.out::print);
    }

    static <T> Stream<T> repeatFromSupplier(Supplier<Stream<T>> supplier) {
        return Stream.generate(supplier).flatMap(s -> s);
    }

    static <T> Stream<T> repeatFromStream(Stream<T> stream) {
        return Stream.generate(() -> stream).flatMap(s -> s);
    }
}
```

As you see, the difference between the `repeatFromSupplier` and `repeatFromStream` methods lies on its argument and on what is passed to the `Stream.generate` method.

While the `repeatFromSupplier` method receives an argument of type `Supplier<Stream<T>>` and passes this argument directly to the `Stream.generate` method, the `repeatFromStream` method receives an argument of type `Stream<T>` and creates a `Supplier<Stream<T>>` by means of the `() -> stream` inline lambda expression, which is immediately passed to the `Stream.generate` method.

I expected both methods to show the same behavior, as I thought the differences were only cosmetic.

However, this code shows different behaviors for the `repeatFromSupplier` and `repeatFromStream` methods. If you run it, you'll notice that the `repeatFromSupplier` method works as expected (it prints `1231231231`), while the `repeatFromStream` method prints `123` and throws an `IllegalStateException: stream has already been operated upon or closed`.

Now, I do know why and when this exception is thrown. I'm not asking about it. Instead, I'd like to know why both methods behave differently.

Comment: Two different calls to `Stream.of(1, 2, 3)` are going to return two separate stream objects.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Is it as simple as that? One creates a new stream, while the other one always return the same stream object?

Comment: Yes, that's all there is to it.  A single stream object can only be consumed once, but creating a new stream each time avoids that issue.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Thank you, I surely need to drink more coffee...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the nominal case of `s1` you call a supplier to create a new stream every time:

```
() -> Stream.of(1, 2, 3)
```

But in the case of `s2`, you create a single stream, and then always return that same instance from the supplier:

```
() -> stream
```

This is essentially the same as this code:

```
Stream<Integer> s = Stream.of(1, 2, 3); // now Stream.of is only executed once
Stream<Integer> s1 = repeatFromSupplier(() -> s);
s1.sequential().limit(10).forEachOrdered(System.out::print);
```

Which also throws an exception.